# format numbering back to round figures of thousands

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I have a column of numbers (Column P) referenced as billions and millions e.g. 2.12B (for 2.12 Billion), 887.99M (for 887.99 Million). The data has been copied and pasted from the internet.
Need help with formula to convert the above examples in the same cells that the data contains rounded to thousands and replace the period/fullstop in the number to coma as a separator e.g. for 2.12B the results to be 2,120,000 and for 887.99M the results to be 887,990.
I am thinking maybe conditional formatting would be best suited because the column will have new data copied and pasted in future that will require return of results as above. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Q1** enter:

```
=--MID(P1,1,LEN(P1)-1)*(IF(RIGHT(P1,1)="M",1000000,(IF(RIGHT(P1,1)="B",1000000000,1))))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you need the conversion **in the same cell**, then a macro would be needed:

```
Sub Konverter()
    Dim r As Range, v As String, s As String

    For Each r In Columns(16).SpecialCells(2)
        v = r.Text
        s = Right(v, 1)
        Select Case s
            Case "M"
                r.Value = 1000000 * CDbl(Mid(v, 1, Len(v) - 1))
            Case "B"
                r.Value = 1000000000 * CDbl(Mid(v, 1, Len(v) - 1))
            Case Else
                r.Value = CDbl(v)
        End Select
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel at hand, to post a working solution, but you need the following:

- MID - function to separate the number from the B or the M
- LEN - function that returns the length of a string
- SUBSTITUTE - function to replace the dot with a comma

Final result should be similar to: =SUBSTITUTE( MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-1), ".", "," ) * IF( MID(A1,LEN(A1)-1,LEN(A1))="M", 1000000, 1000000000 )

I might be off-by-one with some parameters, and I'm working with cell A1 - you should test with a few values and adapt the example to suit your needs.

Once you drag this formula across a column, it will work for all future data.